Integration Issues with vCard SaaS Product: 500 Server Error After Implementing Corcel and JWT
Product: vCard SaaS by InfyOm
Environment: Localhost XAMPP
PHP Version: 8.3
WordPress Version: 6.5
Laravel Version: 10
Hi Stack Overflow Community,
I'm experiencing issues integrating the vCard SaaS product (from InfyOm) with WordPress, and I'm reaching out for assistance.
Integration Methods Tried:
Corcel Integration:
Steps Taken:
Installed and configured the Corcel package according to the Corcel documentation.
Updated config/auth.php to use Corcel as the driver for the users provider.
Ensured all necessary configurations and dependencies were in place.
Issue Encountered: After completing the integration and attempting to log in with WordPress credentials, the application returns a 500 server error.
JWT Integration:
Steps Taken:
Followed the JWT authentication guide for Laravel.
Configured JWT to work with WordPress user authentication.
Made sure all required JWT settings and middleware were correctly implemented.
Issue Encountered: Similarly, when attempting to log in with WordPress or the app’s own credentials, the application returns a 500 server error.
Error Details:
Error Message: 500 Internal Server Error
Log Files: [Include relevant log files or snippets showing the error, if available]
What I've Tried:
Double-checked all configuration settings for both Corcel and JWT integrations.
Verified that there are no conflicts or missing dependencies.
Restarted the server and cleared cache.
Questions:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with the vCard SaaS product when integrating with WordPress?
Are there any specific configurations or steps that might have been missed?
Could the 500 server error be related to compatibility issues with the PHP or WordPress versions I'm using?
Are there any known issues or additional debugging steps I should consider?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information or specific details, please let me know.
Note: I try corcel in basic laravel app and that works but this....
Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Maimoona Qasmi
Software Developer - GECA
